# Creating a modified `filter` function

Tags: scala

Consider the [`filter` function](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.collection.parallel.ParIterableLike$Filter).

I am interested in the following modifications of the filter function, if possible:

- We know for a collection we can do:

> ```
>  case class People(val age: Int) 
>  val a: List[People] = ...
>  a.filter(i => i.age ==10 )
> ```

Or more simply:

```
a.filter(_.age==10 )
```

Any simple way I can define another modified filter that works just like the following (no underline)

```
a.myfilter1( age==10 )
```

- the `filter` function does not work when its argument is no Boolean. Suppose I want to create a modified filter that when a non-Boolean is given, it translates to equality automatically. Here is an example:

> ```
> val anotherPerson: People = ... 
> a.myFilter2(anotherPerson)
> ```

I want the above `myFilter2` to get translated as following:

```
a.filter(_.equals(anotherPerson))
```

Comment: Isn't a.filter(anotherPerson.equals) good enough?

Comment: You can use your own collection type, or use implicits to pimp existing collection types. Either way, not sure it deverse it.

Comment: @Felix I am trying to design a relatively more high level language for my own purpose, and for that I need to define these modified `filter` functions.

Comment: I think there is definitely no *simple* way to achieve what you are aiming at. There might be something using macros or `Dynamic`.

Answer (score 1):

Using implicit def:

```
case class MyFilterable[T](seq: Seq[T]) {
    def suchAFilter(v: Any): Seq[T] = {
      seq.filter(v.equals)
    }   
}

implicit def strongFilter[T](seq: Seq[T]): MyFilterable[T] = {
    MyFilterable(seq)
}


println(List(1,2,3).suchAFilter(2))
```